# woocommerce user registration form without email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, registration

I want to customers can register on woocommerce registration form without email instead of it they can  register with username(not email) and password.
 how i can do that?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email is required filed for every user in WordPress. Woocommerce registration - create users. Emails needed for recovery pass, notifications, etc..

But login possible by username, without email.

Comment: According to WordPress' documentation, wp_create_user also let's you insert users without e-mail, as it is an optional parameter here:https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

Comment: Email is a very important field in user object. What user must doing when lost password?Try create user in Dashboard->Users->Add new.

Comment: Almost all which you can - set email field to non required. But this is bad idea.